# How to access the HTTP headers from within a Firefox toolbar

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, firefox-addon

Specifically I want to read the response HTTP headers when the page is loaded/refreshed from within my Firefox toolbar.

Is this possible? I don't need to write, just read the response headers.

Edit: some people are misunderstanding and suggesting Firebug. I am developing a toolbar, I want to access the header data from my code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an observer for the `http-on-examine-response` notification. That way you will know whenever a server response is received and you can take a look at the headers. For a code example you can have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_HTTP_request_headers - that's essentially the same thing but listening to a different notification.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean about the Observer but how would I iterate over the response headers or pull out a specific header such as Content-length?

Comment: @John: The `subject` parameter of the notification is an `nsIHttpChannel` instance, use [`getResponseHeader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIHttpChannel#getResponseHeader%28%29) to get a particular header or [`visitResponseHeaders()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIHttpChannel#visitResponseHeaders%28%29) to get all of them.

Answer (score -1):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is what I use - activate the Net panel and you can see Headers, Responses and lots more!

Comment: It's Stack Overflow here, not Super User ;) He asked a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to read the HTTP headers through the Firebug Add-On.

Comment: I am developing a toolbar to programmatically access the data, not through the use of other extensions.